# Telerik UI For UWP RadCalendar Control Binding To selected Dates

Tags: telerik, uwp-xaml

In this Telerik doc here:

```
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radcalendar/selection
```

It says:

```
Properties
SelectedDateRange (CalendarDateRange?): Gets or sets the first date range in 
the current selection or returns null if the selection is empty. Setting this 
property in a calendar that supports multiple selections clears existing 
selected ranges and sets the selection to the range specified.

SelectedDateRanges (CalendarDateRangeCollection): Holds a collection of all 
selection ranges.
```

I am having trouble binding to the calendar I am mis-understanding the requirements and there is no example of how to do it. I am using A ViewModel approach. My XAML:

```
<input:RadCalendar
 Name="cal"
 SelectedDateRange="{x:Bind viewModel.selectedCalendarDateRange, Mode=TwoWay}"
 SelectionMode="Multiple"
 <input:RadCalendar.ContextFlyout>
     <MenuFlyout>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Command="{x:Bind viewModel.calendarSelectCommand}">OK</MenuFlyoutItem>
     </MenuFlyout>
 </input:RadCalendar.ContextFlyout>
```

In my ViewModel:

```
  public CalendarDateRange?  selectedCalendarDateRange {get=>_calendarDateRange;
  set => SetProperty(ref _calendarDateRange,value); }
```

I am selecting some dates and on mouse up I I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in 
an un-representable DateTime.  
Parameter name: value
at System.DateTime.AddTicks(Int64 value)
at  Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input.CalendarDateRange.
IntersectsWithRange(CalendarDateRange otherDateRange)
at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input.
CalendarDateRangeCollection.MergeCollidingRanges
(CalendarDateRange newDataRange, Int32 currentIndex)
at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Input.
CalendarDateRangeCollection.AddDateRange(CalendarD
```

How do I correctly set up the binding on this control?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the type of the **selectedCalendarDateRange** property of your ViewModel does not match the type of the **SelectedDateRange** property of the RadCalendar. Note that there is a question mark after the type of the SelectedDateRange. This makes it nullable type. You can try adding the same question mark after the type of the property in your ViewModel, something like this:

```
  public CalendarDateRange?  selectedCalendarDateRange {get=>_calendarDateRange; set => SetProperty(ref _calendarDateRange,value); }
```

The field **_calendarDateRange** should also be nullable.

Comment: Yes I have changed it nullable but still no go - thanks anyhow.